# How to retrieve a Json file using the best way

Tags: java, android, json, http, networking

I want to display the titles of videos which contains a specific SubString such as for example `videoName="apple"`:

So in order to perform this task I wrote a code to retrieve a Json file and get all entries that related to this name: ("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+videoName+"&v=2&alt=json")
BUT unfortunately I had exception at this statement:

```
HttpResponse res = cli.execute(g);
```

**This is the function I wrote to get the json file:**

```
String GetUrlBody (String Url ){


            Log.d("s18", "ok");


            HttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

            Log.d("s19", "ok");


            HttpGet g = new HttpGet(Url); 

            Log.d("s20", "ok");


            try{

                Log.d("s21", "ok");

            HttpResponse res = cli.execute(g);

            Log.d("s22", "ok");


            if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                Log.d("s23", "ok");


                String s =
            EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 

                Log.d("s24", "ok");


                return s; 

            }else {

                Log.d("s25", "ok");

                return "Not Found"; 


            }




            }catch(Exception exx){

                Log.d("s26", "ok");

                Log.d("s27", exx.getMessage());



            }




            return null; 
        }
```

**All my code:**

```
package com.example.task_10_vedioserach;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView vediolist;
    ImageButton search;
    Button history;
    EditText title;
    /////////////////
    ArrayList<String > vl; 
    ArrayAdapter< String > ad ; 
    ProgressDialog pd ; 
    /////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vediolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vedioList);
        search = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
        history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);
        title=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.vedioName);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

          vl = new ArrayList<String>(); 
          ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , android.R.id.text1,vl); 

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          Log.d("s0", "ok");

          search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String vedioName=title.getText().toString();
                Log.d("s1", "ok");
                new conn().execute("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+vedioName+"&v=2&alt=json"); 
                Log.d("s2", "ok");
            }
        });

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this); 
        pd.setMessage("Wait Loading .... "); 
        pd.setCancelable(false); 
        vediolist.setAdapter(ad); 

    }



    class conn extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("s3", "ok");
             pd.show(); 
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("s4", "ok");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Log.d("s5", "ok");
            String s = GetUrlBody(arg0[0]); 
            Log.d("s6", "ok");
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Log.d("s7", "ok");


        try{

            Log.d("s8", "ok");

            JSONObject jo =(JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();

            Log.d("s9", "ok");


        JSONObject feed = jo.optJSONObject("feed");
        Log.d("s10", "ok");

        JSONArray ent = feed.optJSONArray("entry");
        Log.d("s11", "ok");



        for(int i = 0 ; i<ent.length() ; i++){

        String ti = ent.getJSONObject(i).
                getJSONObject("title").getString("$t");
        vl.add(ti); 


        }

        Log.d("s12", "ok");


        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("s13", "ok");

        }catch(Exception exx) {
            Log.d("s14", "ok");

        }

        Log.d("s15", "ok");

            pd.dismiss(); 
            Log.d("s16", "ok");

            super.onPostExecute(result); 
            Log.d("s17", "ok");


        } 




        String GetUrlBody (String Url ){


            Log.d("s18", "ok");


            HttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

            Log.d("s19", "ok");


            HttpGet g = new HttpGet(Url); 

            Log.d("s20", "ok");


            try{

                Log.d("s21", "ok");

            HttpResponse res = cli.execute(g);

            Log.d("s22", "ok");


            if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                Log.d("s23", "ok");


                String s =
            EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 

                Log.d("s24", "ok");


                return s; 

            }else {

                Log.d("s25", "ok");

                return "Not Found"; 


            }




            }catch(Exception exx){

                Log.d("s26", "ok");

                Log.d("s27", exx.getMessage());



            }




            return null; 
        }



    }
```

**this is the full Stacktrace:** [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cx2exrjtqobd03v/FullStackTrace.txt)

Comment: Do you have Internet permission in Manifest file? `<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>`

Comment: u have null value try to use if(jdata.has("data")) before nullable value

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend using something like GSON and Jackson. Links bellow:

GSON:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/
http://albertattard.blogspot.co.at/2009/06/practical-example-of-gson.html

Jackson:
http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Now you have to understand that using these tools is not just "for the lazy". They are well built and fast mappers. They will get the job done quicker and easier than any algorithm / method you alone can think of in a short amount of time. Hope this helps!